# Calling Microsoft QnA maker API from Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, azure-cognitive-services

This is the code sample that I have written

```js
var http=require('http');

var demo=[];
console.log("Doing the Post Operations...");
// Define an demo object with properties and values. This object will be used for POST request.

var demo=JSON.stringify({"question":"hi"});


var extServerOptionsPost={
host:'http://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0',
path:'/knowledgebases/<my kb id>/generateAnswer',
method:'POST',
headers:{
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'my key',
'Content-Type':'application/json'
}
};

var reqPost=http.request(extServerOptionsPost,function(res){
console.log("response statusCode: ",res.statusCode);
res.on('data',function(data){
console.log('Posting Result:\n');
process.stdout.write(data);
console.log('\n\n POST Operation Completed');
});
});


reqPost.write(demo);
reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error',function(e){
 console.error(e);
});
```

When I am running it, it shows the following error. 
[image]

How to get around this error? This is the first time I'm calling a third party API from node. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host name should not include the protocol, and, incidentally, it needs to be https, not http.  So:

```
var extServerOptionsPost={
  host:'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
  path:'/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/' + your_kb + '/generateAnswer',
  port:443,
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':your_key,
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.Its working perfectly.

Comment: I seem to have followed every step but I get the Error: read ECONNRESET. Do you have any idea what the issue may stem from?